# Вывод float с форматированием

Tags: c++, format

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
int main()
{
    float a = 1.f;
    std::cout << std::showpoint << a << ' ' << a/3;
}
```

Вывод с разным количеством символов (7 и 8):

> 1.00000 0.333333

При других числах:

```
#include <iomanip>
int main()
{
    float a = 10.f; // не 1.f
    std::cout << std::showpoint << a << ' ' << a/3;
}
```

Вывод с одинаковым количеством символов (7 и 7):

> 10.0000 3.33333

Почему так? Как всегда получать одинаковое количество символов? Мне это нужно для красивого вывода на консоль/в файл с форматированием.

Comment: `setw` не хотите использовать для выравнивания? Все ж таки выравнивать за счет уменьшения количества знаков после запятой - фактически, сдвигая запятую - некрасиво...

Comment: @Harry как `setw` будет с `float` работать? Получается разное кол-во символов

Comment: @Harry например, для единицы будет 5 символов, а для 1/3 - 8

Comment: @Harry надо вывести ровно друг под другом как в таблице

Comment: Посмотрите тут - http://ideone.com/PHu5xX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я бы выравнивал примерно так:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

double v1[] =
{
    1.0, 33.15, 30/3.0, 2.718281828
};

double v2[] =
{
    1.0, 33.15*3, 321/3.0, 2.718281828*3.14
};

int main()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
    {
        cout << fixed << right << setprecision(8) << setw(12) << v1[i]
             << " | " << setw(12) << v2[i] << endl;
    }
}
```

Результат:

```
  1.00000000 |   1.00000000
 33.15000000 |  99.45000000
 10.00000000 | 107.00000000
  2.71828183 |   8.53540494
```